# ViewModel error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I was given some help on here recently and set up a view model called RegisterViewModel containing fields from (currently) two different models. This worked and I can use it to register a new user along with related user info. My problem is viewing the details from this same view model. In the Usee controller in my 'Details' method I have the same code -

```
public ViewResult Details(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
        {
            TRSContext context = new TRSContext();
            User currentuser = context.Users
                .Include(i => i.UserDetails)
                .Where(i => i.UserName == viewModel.UserName)
                .Single();

            currentuser.UserDetails = new UserDetails();

            return View(userRepository.Find(viewModel.UserName));
        }
```

But I am getting the error -

**Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type**

for the line -

**(i => i.UserDetails)**

Any ideas what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `.Include("UserDetails")` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that removes that error but I now get another - Sequence contains no elements

Comment: @MartinMcMahon that's a different problem. Your calling `Single` which will throw an exception if the query returns 0 results. If your query *can* be empty then your best returning `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask another question for that then :)

Answer (score 1):

The lambda version of `Include` was introduced in [EF CTP4](http://romiller.com/2010/07/14/ef-ctp4-tips-tricks-include-with-lambda/), unless you have that you need to use a string i.e.

```
.Include("UserDetails")
```